# synchronization between client and server

Tags: java, synchronization

I'm in trouble of this kind of problem:

A asks if B is online. B receives and responses to A: I'm online. Just after B sends this response, B is turned off. But A receives the response from B and believes B is online.

I encounter this problem when coding servers in Java. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Umm... no :) This kind of uncertainty is the essential nature of distributed systems.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So there is no solutions to optimize it? My problem is if A believes B is there, it will cause incoherent data problem.

Comment: Whatever adjustments you do, it will just reduce the probability of a bad outcome. Look at it this way: at some point in time `t` you will receive the last message from B according to your fault-tolerant protocol. At time `t+1` B fails. There's no way around this. In other words, you shouldn't build a system based on the belief that the other node is alive.

Comment: Supposed A can keep asking B whether B is online, so you can start a heartbeat process in B to inform A.

Comment: @artificerPi It won't solve OP's problem because B can fail as soon as it sends a heartbeat. There will be uncertainty until the next heartbeat is due. In other words, there will _always_ be the same amount of uncertainty.

Comment: You can send the same request to another node after B didn't send response in some limit.

Comment: @olsli But B did response and just 1 nanosecond after, B left. A can receive the response but cannot know B's leaving.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for your suggestion. I'm trying to modify my mechanism in my system.